# React Native не устанавливается на эмулятор

Tags: android-sdk, react-native

Пробую собрать необходимый минимум для работы React Native, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.937 secs Could not install the app on the device, read
>   the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

При том, что `Android_Home` указан [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Дело в том, что ANDROID_HOME и JAVA_HOME были добавлены при уже открытой студии, и она не видела этих изменений.

Достаточно было перезапустить студию после внесенных путей, и он заработал.